# Footer floating over main content

Tags: html, css, xhtml, responsive-design

So I have a site that scales down gracefully in the browser window but I am having an issue with the content outside of my header. The main and footer elements are just hovering in the middle of all my content. I believe it may be something to do with the height I set to the header but I need to space out all the elements within that correctly.

Heres a link to the site: http://nathanlangley.co.uk/sitev5/index.html

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

"I believe it may be something to do with the height I set to the header"

I just followed your link, and, following your suggestion, tried taking the height attribute off the header. It fixes it.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I did this but the content within the header just folds in on itself without a height.

Comment: Didn't happen according to my tests (Chrome, FF, IE). Seeing as the layout's broken anyway (because of a specified height), why not remove the height on the site then try to solve the problem of the collapsed header?